# Google Search Console performance UI

Tags: google-search-console, google-apis-explorer

Perhaps I've missed this in the docs but I'm trying to figure out why at the impressions and clicks within the tabs at bottom of the google search console UI: queries, pages, countries, devices, search appearance, dates are different from the clicks/impressions in blue / purple at the top of the page?

When I click on `Devices` and add up the total impressions its different from the total impressions show on the main UI page which shows 91.8k and 9.27k clicks. Same goes for Countries tab which matches Devices tab. See picture for what I'm referring to:

[image]

Why are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation can be seen on the [Google webmaster](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en) site under "Data discrepancies"